# Why "самый лучший" instead of "лучший"?

Tags: значения, прилагательные, superlative

> Она далеко не **самая лучшая** кандидатура на такую роль.
>
> vs: Она далеко не **лучшая** кандидатура на такую роль.

The phrasing "самая лучшая" pulled me up short because... Doesn't it sound like "the most best"? Why is "лучший" preceded by "самый", even though "лучший", unlike "красивый", can stand on its own as a full-fledged superlative adjective?

Comment: You can think of it as 'the very best' rather than 'most best'. It might not be entirely grammatically correct, but it sounds just fine in casual speech.

Comment: Russian equivalent of **the most best** would be **наиболее лучший** which is ungrammatical indeed

Answer (score 4):

Here's a cookie cutter answer of the Gramota.ru information service:

> [**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer/?s=%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9)
>
> Это корректное и допустимое сочетание для разговорной речи, в ситуации
>   непринужденного общения. Но в образцовой литературной речи его лучше
>   избегать.

---

> *Doesn't it sound like "the most best"?*

It may or may not because **лучший** is also an *inflectable comparative* form which isn't perceived as *superlative*, similarly to difference in degree between **хорошо** and **лучше**.

<sup>Ref. [*Синтетические префиксальные формы суперлатива* in *"Грамматическая семантика. Русский язык в типологической перспективе"*
by Юрий Князев](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=hWjMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA222&lpg=PA222&dq#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

It's possible that it's a variant of **наилучший** which is a superlative form derived synthetically from synthetic  comparative form (**лучший**) instead of analytically from the positive one (**самый + хороший**), similarly to **наихудший**, **наивысший**, **наименьший**,  **наисильнейший**, **наипростейший**, **наимоднейший** etc.

> наи (без удар.) (книжн.). Приставка, присоединяемая к форме
>   превосходной, реже сравнительной степени прилагательных и наречий и
>   придающая этим прилагательным и наречиям **значение предельной степени
>   качества**, напр. наилучший, наибольший, наименьший, наиспособнейший,
>   наиболее, наименее, наичаще и т. п.

[*Толковый словарь Ушакова 1935-40 гг.*](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/870622#sel=5:1,6:10)

Also acceptable are collocations such as [**самый простейший**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%22&newwindow=1&ei=1kS6W-PhOo6QmgWlg6-4Dg), **самый худший**, **самый старший**, **самый младший**, [**самый низший**](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&source=hp&ei=IGG6W_OhMYKwsAHPxriAAw&q="%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9"), **самый меньший**

> **Меньший**
>
> меньшая, меньшее. 1. Сравн. ст. к малый и к маленький. Из двух
>   предложенных комнат выбрал меньшую. 2. Превосх. ст. к тем же прил.;
>   **самый меньший**, меньший из всех (книжн.). Взять меньшее из данных
>   количеств. 3. То же, что младший (разг. редко, чаще меньшой). Меньший
>   сын. По меньшей мере - см. мера. **Самое меньшее** - не менее, по меньшей
>   мере. Придется заплатить самое меньшее сто рублей.

[*Толковый словарь Ушакова 1935-40 гг.*](http://www.endic.ru/ushakov/Menshij-29458.html)

This is again because **худший**, **старший**, **младший**, **низший**, **меньший** are inflectable comparative forms

**`Positive`**          **`Comparative`**          **`Superlative`**

простой               простейший         самый простой/простейший
плохой/худой         худший 
             самый плохой/худший
старый                  старший             самый старый/старший
молодой                младший           самый молодой/младший
низкий                    низший               самый низкий/низший
маленький            меньший          самый маленький/меньший
тонкий                    тощий                  самый тонкий/тощий

I believe it might be due to the fact of inflectable comparative adjectives being perceived as denoting a quality in its own right that adjunction of **самый** has become possible.

In Ukrainian on the other hand *inflectable comparative* form is a rule and not an exception like in Russian.

<sup>Further read [«Избранные работы по русистике. Фонология. Морфонология. Морфология. Орфография. Лексикография» chapter «Употребление форм прилагательных с суффиксом -ейш- (-айш-) в значении сравнительной степени в русском литературном языке XIX-XX вв.»](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=STRqAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>